# Cell row reference coming from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I need to make Google Sheets evoke the row number for a cell reference by pointing to another cell. I have a form with different cells that point to another sheet (Sheet1!). All the cells always point to a cell of a similar row number; only the column changes.

For example: the `Name` field points to Sheet1!C2, `Address` points to Sheet1!D2, `Phone Number` points to Sheet1!E2.

I want to have a single cell where I can type the row number, so that if I were to type in `5` in such cell, it will automatically make the previous fields point to C5, D5, E5.

Is there a way of doing this?

<sub>I am trying to avoid having to go into each cell and manually change the `2` to a `5` or any other number.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`INDIRECT` function](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/M0STpJexGX8%5B1-25%5D).

Here is how it works:

[image]

Comment: The link doesn't work any more. If there isn't an updated link, that line should be removed.