# Referencing a cell from another sheet using a value in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find a way to reference a cell from another sheet using a value in another cell from the "home sheet." I've tried to use `INDIRECT` but I'm not quite sure how to use it when the cell I'm trying to reference is from another sheet.

For example:

Let's say that I have two sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Cell B30 of Sheet2 contains data I want to be referenced in cell A2 of Sheet1. In Sheet1, the cell A1 contains the number 30.

So in cell A2 of Sheet1, I want to reference cell Sheet2!B<the number that is in Sheet1!A1>.

Does anyone know how I can go about this, if I can at all? As mentioned I tried using `INDIRECT` but not exactly sure if this works if the cell referenced is from another sheet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cell row reference coming from another cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29802/cell-row-reference-coming-from-another-cell)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!B" & A1)
```

[image]       [image]
<sub>left: Sheet 1; right: Sheet 2</sub>